# Proguard retrace tool's output

Tags: android, eclipse, obfuscation, proguard

I'm experimenting with proguard now that it's easier to use from
within eclipse. I've exported a signed version of my app with a
deliberate bug that causes a crash for testing. After I get the stack
trace and run retrace -verbose mapping.txt stack.txt, instead of
giving me where the error occurs, it gives me the class where error
happens and list a of methods, one of which is the method where the
exception happens.

I've used the official guide for all of this and edited the logcat stack trace capture to be in the same format as the dev console. Anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your obfuscated code doesn't contain line number information, mapping an obfuscated method name (like 'a') to the original method name is no longer unambiguously possible, due to name overloading. The [examples in the ReTrace manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/tools/retrace#examples) illustrate the difference.

To avoid this effect, you can preserve line number information in the obfuscation step, as shown in an [example in the ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#stacktrace).

Comment: The retrace manual doesn't seem to be accessible as of today. I have enabled `LineNumberTable` etc, and I can see line numbers in my mapping file, but retrace still can't disambiguate between the methods.

Comment: May want to fix the link - the page no longer exists.