# ANR has no line number

Tags: android, obfuscation, stack-trace

I have received an ANR from an end user, but the top line (in my code) has no line number.  Why is that, and how am I supposed to identify the error?  The code is obfuscated using progaurd.

More specifically, the first few lines of my stack trace are:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.perinote.perinote.main.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(Unknown Source)
 at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:950)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proguard retrace tool's output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619301/proguard-retrace-tools-output)

Comment: How long is your `onOptionsItemSelected()` method? If you're still having an issue, post it.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, regarding "long".  If you mean how many lines is my function, it's about 260.  Not sure how that's relevant, though.